# How can i specify struct lifetime in rust implementation for trait with static lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have this code:

```
// engine.rs
pub struct Engine<'a, 'b> {
    // ...some code
    dispatcher: Dispatcher<'a, 'b>
}

impl<'a, 'b> GameState for Engine<'a, 'b> { // <- Error
    fn tick(&mut self, ctx: &mut BTerm) {
        todo!()
    }
}

// dispatcher.rs (lib file)
pub struct Dispatcher<'a, 'b> {
    //...some code
}

// gamestate.rs (lib file)
pub trait GameState: 'static {
    fn tick(&mut self, ctx: &mut BTerm);
}
```

I need the dispatcher field in the structure, but when specifying the field type, I also need to specify the lifetime. This is not a problem as long as I don't have to specify a lifetime in the `GameState` implementation block which has a static lifetime. When I try to specify the lifetime there, I get an error. I can't change the `GameState` and `Dispatcher` because it's library code and I need the dispatcher field in the struct. How can I solve this problem?

Full error text:

```
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
  --> src/engine.rs:14:14
   |
14 | impl<'a, 'b> GameState for Engine<'a, 'b> {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime `'b` as defined here
  --> src/engine.rs:14:10
   |
14 | impl<'a, 'b> GameState for Engine<'a, 'b> {
   |          ^^
   = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
```

Comment: `impl GameState for Engine<'static, 'static>` ?

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks, it works. And I just accidentally discovered that if you specify Dispatcher<'static, 'static> everywhere inside the Engine and its methods, it also works. Can you explain that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define all lifetimes that `Engine` contains as `'static` because by writing `trait Gamestate: 'static` you say that `Gamestate` can only be implemented for things that contain no references that live shorter than `'static` but by trying to define it for a struct containing references of a generic lifetime `'a` which you have to assume can be any lifetime in practice this obviously isn't fulfilled.

Wether you do it by directly secifying it in `Engine`, `Dispatcher` or by passing `'static` as generic parameters is up to you to decide, do you need to support non-static lifetimes in a `Engine`? Then you definitely can't use `'static` in it's definition, similar for `Dispatcher`.